# How to make sure a daily time trigger runs?

Tags: google-apps-script

I setup two sets of scripts. One that checks conditions in a google-sheet every hour, and sends me an email if a value is above a limit. (The sheet is updated every hour through Supermetrics).
The second script resets a column I use to "timeout" a row from sending me an email again, if it already has done so this day. This script runs only once a day.

My problem is that now and then the scripts don't run. After some testing it seems to be about 20% of the times, it does'nt run.

This is not a big deal for the hour-by-hour check. But I need my daily check to run once a day (the specific time doesn't matter all that much, but I really need it to rune some time during the day).

Does anyone know of a way to make sure of this? Alternatively, do you know of a better way to "timeout" the email so it won't spam me?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure the script doesn't run? If you don't already, you can include some debugging checks like `console.log("running daily script")` at the start of the function. Then you can verify by consulting Stackdriver that the functions actually ran. Without seeing the code you run, or an idea of the magnitude of your spreadsheet, we can't offer alternate reasons for why it appears to fail to run.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the time to go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: Values had not changed, but what I mainly used as a check was sending an email. I guess that could fail by itself, and that would not be an issue. But I will try log, and see if that can give me some more info.

The main test I did was a function that did not do much, but it did send me an email. I set it to run every 5 minutes. and it did .. mostly.. Now and then it didn't run for 1-2 periods.

The spreadsheet is about 100x25 cells. Not particularly large.

Thank you.

Comment: You might want to set your notifications on the trigger to immediate so that you'll get an email fairly soon after each failure telling you what the problem is.  My experience is that triggers run very reliably.  I've tested them by having them write time to a text file just to see how reliable they were and the only problems I've seen are problems in my scripts.